# Why a key has to be removed from selectedKeys

Tags: java, nio

This is a simple server, I used nc as clients to connect to the server, the first client went through and entered the acceptHandler. However, the second client cannot trigger the select to return a number greater than 0 (the return value of select is 0). I see that removing the processed key will resolve the issue, what I don't understand is that why a new connection cannot trigger an event when the serverSocket is still registered with the selector

```
  static ServerSocketChannel server;
  static Selector selector;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9090));
    server.configureBlocking(false);
    selector = Selector.open();
    server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    while (true) {
      int num;
      while ((num = selector.select()) > 0) {
        
        Set<SelectionKey> selectionKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> iter = selectionKeys.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
          SelectionKey sk = iter.next();
//          iter.remove();
          if (sk.isAcceptable()) {
            acceptHandler(sk);
          } else if (sk.isReadable()) {
            readHandler(sk);
          } 
        }
      }

    }
  }

  public static void acceptHandler(SelectionKey sk) {
    System.out.println("accept handle");
    ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) sk.channel();
    SocketChannel client = null;
    try {
      client = server.accept();   // return null if no pending connections

      if (client != null) {
        client.configureBlocking(false);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(65535);
        client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, buffer);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) of `Selector`: "*For a channel that is ready for at least one such operation ... 1. If the channel's key is not already in the selected-key set then it is added to that set ... 2. Otherwise the channel's key is already in the selected-key set, .... Any readiness information previously recorded in the ready set is preserved"* and for `select()`: *"Returns: The number of keys, possibly zero, whose ready-operation sets were updated"*

Comment: I've read that, but still a bit confused. So from my understanding, the state of the server key is not changed and still preserved in the ready-operation set even though meanwhile it can react to the new incoming connections, however, the select() will just return 0, because the ready-operation set for that selector is not updated according the return statement. Am I right?

Comment: channel key is still on selected-key set (it was not removed) -> readiness information is preserved, that is, not updated -> returned value is zero (number of keys that were updated)

Comment: got it. thanks a lot